# Gnuplot for loop with increment smaller then 1

Tags: gnuplot

I was trying to plot the following

```
plot for [h=0:2:0.1] sin(h*x)
```

But it gives the following error

```
gnuplot> plot for [h=0:2:0.1] sin(x*h)
                     ^
         Expecting iterator     for [<var> = <start> : <end> {: <incr>}]
         or for [<var> in "string of words"]
```

But the following line works just fine

```
plot for [h=0:2:1.1] sin(x*h)
```

Is this a bug or it is supposed to work this way? I mean, why it is not accepting increments smaller than 1?

I'm using the following version of gnuplot

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gnuplot supports iterations only with integer values (see documentation section "For loops in plot command", p 98). Values smaller then `1` are casted as integer to `0`, which is not allowed. Using e.g.

```
plot for [h=0:3:1.5] sin(x*h) title sprintf('%.1f', h)
```

plots four curves with `h` having the values `0, 1, 2, 3`. To use smaller values you must scale the iteration value later:

```
plot for [h=0:20:1] sin(0.1*h*x)
```

Comment: I asked this because I found this [link](http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/iteration/) where the author use this command: `plot for [angle=360:0:-2.5]`. So is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong in the sense, that he actual increment is `-2`, which still gives you a reasonable result for the examples shown there.

Comment: Nice to know. I'll try to make a comment in the page warning for this problem.

Comment: Does it make sense that no errormessage (or warning at least) is issued if a noninteger is fed to the iterator structure?

Comment: @Karl I guess there are too many places where such casts or conversions are performed silently, e.g. string -> float, float -> int etc: `plot 'file' using (column(1.1)):2`, `plot for [i=0:2:"1.3"] i*x`, `plot x * "1.1"`. Gnuplot also has integer division, which is not what some people expect, `print 5/2` -> `2`. I know only of some operators which give an error when not used with integers: `print 1.2 << 2`, `print 1.2 & 2`, `print 2.2 % 2`. I don't know if it would make sense to give an error in the case of iterations. However, the error message could be better for `plot for [i=0:1:0.1] x`.

Comment: Indeed, integer division always causes some kind of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Christoph's answer, another way to do arbitrary increment loops without the need to do the scaling within the function is to define a list of values that contains all the elements to loop through. This can easily be done with a system call to `seq`:

```
list(start,end,increment)=system(sprintf("seq %g %g %g", start, increment, end))
plot for [i in list(0.,1.,0.1)] sin(i*x)
```

[image]

An equivalent gnuplot-only solution (proposed by Karl in the comments) that will work also if `seq` is not available is the following:

```
start=0.; end=1.; inc=0.1
list = ""; a=start-inc; while (a<end) {list=list.sprintf(" %.3f",a=a+inc)}
plot for [i in list] sin(i*x)
```

Note that `while` loops are only available since gnuplot 4.6.

Comment: I'd like to point out that since `seq` is a system call, it may not be available in all platforms. `seq` is not available in Windows (without some unix environment of course) by default. But it is a way to accomplish what I proposed in the question.

Comment: @McLeary You're absolutely right. However, a gnuplot-only solution involving for example `do for` and recursively printing to a variable, while doable, would be more cumbersome than Christoph's solution (so I'm not even going to bother posting it). I am not familiar with gnuplot under Windows, but perhaps some alternative solution similar to the one above is possible.

Comment: `list = ""; a=start-inc; while (a<end) {list=list.sprintf(" %.3f",a=a+inc)}` does the same in one line.

Comment: @Karl Thanks for your suggestion, I forgot new gnuplot versions have access to `while` loops. I will add it to the answer. While not as flexible as a function that can be called any time after being defined, it is a gnuplot-only solution and will work under any platform.